# Scraping HTML table from with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to do some web scraping on this tables website (https://prosettings.net/cs-go-pro-settings-gear-list/) to practice some python skills however it does not return a full table but just some random rows.

I already tried this code with order tables and it works fine so, idk what I am doing wrong.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://prosettings.net/cs-go-pro-settings-gear-list/'
page = requests.get(url)
website = page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(website, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'table_1'})

headers = []
for i in table.find_all('th'):
    titles = i.text.strip()
    headers.append(titles)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)

for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    data = row.find_all('td')
    row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
    length = len(df)
    df.loc[length] = row_data

print(df)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you fetched the body of this page with `wget` or `curl`?  The HTML as delivered only contains the first 10 items, which you get.  The rest of the table you see in your browser is built dynamically, with Javascript.  You would have to use something like Selenium to get the dynamic information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically from other URL. To load the data into pandas DataFrame and CSV file you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://prosettings.net/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=55"

params = {
    "draw": "1",
    "columns[0][data]": "0",
    "columns[0][name]": "rank",
    "columns[0][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[0][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[0][search][value]": "",
    "columns[0][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[1][data]": "1",
    "columns[1][name]": "team",
    "columns[1][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[1][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[1][search][value]": "",
    "columns[1][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[2][data]": "2",
    "columns[2][name]": "player",
    "columns[2][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[2][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[2][search][value]": "",
    "columns[2][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[3][data]": "3",
    "columns[3][name]": "role",
    "columns[3][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[3][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[3][search][value]": "",
    "columns[3][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[4][data]": "4",
    "columns[4][name]": "mouse",
    "columns[4][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[4][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[4][search][value]": "",
    "columns[4][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[5][data]": "5",
    "columns[5][name]": "hz",
    "columns[5][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[5][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[5][search][value]": "",
    "columns[5][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[6][data]": "6",
    "columns[6][name]": "dpi",
    "columns[6][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[6][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[6][search][value]": "",
    "columns[6][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[7][data]": "7",
    "columns[7][name]": "sensitivity",
    "columns[7][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[7][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[7][search][value]": "",
    "columns[7][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[8][data]": "8",
    "columns[8][name]": "edpi",
    "columns[8][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[8][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[8][search][value]": "",
    "columns[8][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[9][data]": "9",
    "columns[9][name]": "zoomsens",
    "columns[9][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[9][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[9][search][value]": "",
    "columns[9][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[10][data]": "10",
    "columns[10][name]": "mouseaccel",
    "columns[10][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[10][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[10][search][value]": "",
    "columns[10][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[11][data]": "11",
    "columns[11][name]": "windowssens",
    "columns[11][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[11][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[11][search][value]": "",
    "columns[11][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[12][data]": "12",
    "columns[12][name]": "rawinput",
    "columns[12][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[12][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[12][search][value]": "",
    "columns[12][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[13][data]": "13",
    "columns[13][name]": "monitor",
    "columns[13][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[13][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[13][search][value]": "",
    "columns[13][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[14][data]": "14",
    "columns[14][name]": "hz_1",
    "columns[14][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[14][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[14][search][value]": "",
    "columns[14][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[15][data]": "15",
    "columns[15][name]": "gpu",
    "columns[15][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[15][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[15][search][value]": "",
    "columns[15][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[16][data]": "16",
    "columns[16][name]": "resolution",
    "columns[16][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[16][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[16][search][value]": "",
    "columns[16][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[17][data]": "17",
    "columns[17][name]": "aspectratio",
    "columns[17][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[17][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[17][search][value]": "",
    "columns[17][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[18][data]": "18",
    "columns[18][name]": "scalingmode",
    "columns[18][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[18][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[18][search][value]": "",
    "columns[18][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[19][data]": "19",
    "columns[19][name]": "mousepad",
    "columns[19][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[19][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[19][search][value]": "",
    "columns[19][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[20][data]": "20",
    "columns[20][name]": "keyboard",
    "columns[20][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[20][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[20][search][value]": "",
    "columns[20][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[21][data]": "21",
    "columns[21][name]": "headset",
    "columns[21][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[21][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[21][search][value]": "",
    "columns[21][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[22][data]": "22",
    "columns[22][name]": "cfgcrosshair",
    "columns[22][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[22][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[22][search][value]": "",
    "columns[22][search][regex]": "false",
    "order[0][column]": "0",
    "order[0][dir]": "asc",
    "start": "0",
    "length": "-1",
    "search[value]": "",
    "search[regex]": "false",
    "wdtNonce": "b1dbb06767",
}


df = pd.DataFrame(requests.post(url, data=params).json()["data"])
df = df.transform(
    lambda x: [
        BeautifulSoup(v, "html.parser").get_text(strip=True)
        if isinstance(v, str)
        else v
        for v in x
    ],
    axis=1,
)

print(df.head().to_markdown())
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | NaVi | Boombl4 | Rifler | Zowie EC1 | 1,000 | 400 | 1.45 | 580 | 0.86 | 0 | 6 | 1 | BenQ XL2546 | 240 | RTX 3090 | 1280x960 | 4:3 | STR | Logitech G640 | SteelSeries APEX M750 TKL | Logitech G Pro X Headset | CONFIG |
| 1 | 1 | NaVi | electronic | Rifler | Logitech G Pro X Superlight White | 1,000 | 400 | 2.2 | 880 | 1.05 | 0 | 6 | 1 | BenQ XL2546K | 240 | RX 6900 XT | 1280x960 | 4:3 | STR | Logitech G640 | Logitech G915 TKL White | Logitech G Pro X Wireless Headset | CONFIG |
| 2 | 1 | NaVi | s1mple | AWPer | Logitech G Pro X Superlight Magenta | 1,000 | 400 | 3.09 | 1,236 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 1 | BenQ XL2546K | 240 | RTX 3090 | 1280x960 | 4:3 | STR | HATOR It's nice to be s1mple | Logitech G915 TKL | Logitech G Pro X Headset | CONFIG |
| 3 | 1 | NaVi | Perfecto | Rifler | Logitech G Pro X Superlight Magenta | 1,000 | 800 | 0.9 | 720 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 1 | BenQ XL2546K | 240 | RX 6900 XT | 1280x960 | 4:3 | STR | Logitech G640 | Logitech G915 TKL | Logitech G Pro X Headset | CONFIG |
| 4 | 1 | NaVi | b1t | Rifler | Logitech G Pro X Superlight White | 1,000 | 400 | 1.42 | 568 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 1 | BenQ XL2546 | 240 | RTX 3080 | 1280x960 | 4:3 | STR | Zowie G-SR | Logitech G Pro X Mechanical Keyboard | Logitech G Pro X Headset | CONFIG |

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]